# scala class member macro implementation

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I always thought that macro declarations and implementation need to be defined as in the tutorials:

```scala
object Impl {
    def m(c: Context)(body: c.Expr[Unit]): c.Expr[T] = ???
}
class Usage {
    def m(body: Unit): T = macro Impl.m = ???
}
```

However now I came across:

```scala
class RecordMacros(val c: Context) {
    import c.universe._
    def apply_impl[Rep: c.WeakTypeTag](method: c.Expr[String])(v: c.Expr[(String, Any)]*): c.Expr[Any] = ???
}
```

source: https://github.com/TiarkRompf/virtualization-lms-core/blob/macro-trans/src/common/Records.scala

What is the difference, is it about refactoring the context out from each method?
Also the class doesn't seem to be instantiated before the method is accessed.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called macro bundles available in 2.11 only and yes that's what they are for. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/bundles.html

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't google the right words then